# 2D Rectangular Packing Algorithm for Identical Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, rectangles, bin-packing

Let's say i have been provided with 20 rectangles of a certain size, eg. 400x300.
I have an paper that is infinitely long but only 1200 wide. How can i fit the rectangles on the paper to reduce the amount of waste possible? I'll try to explain waste using a diagram below :

```
_________________________
|
|
|
|
|
|_________________________
```

So, Above is infinite paper. Below is one way to pack 4 rectangles of size 400x300

```
_________________________
|     |  -
|_____|__-
|   |    |
|___|_ __|
|     |  -
|_____|__-__________________
```

Now, this is a very simple example. However, the waste is the area not covered by rectangles behind the line indicated by the - (hyphen)

Is there an algorithm that provided qty, width, height, and height of paper in which rectangles are to packed, can then provided the area that is wasted and the total area. Is there a possible similar example / implementation that i can take a look at ?

The rectangles themselves can be rotated so therefore, won't technically be identical. Their sizes/area is however same.

Comment: This is trivial if all rectangles are of the same dimensions.

Comment: @Redu Not necessarily. The rectangles can be rotated. 

I could place all rectangles on the top side of the canvas / paper and cover a large length. That way i have a fairly large amount of waste. I could pack them all together perpendicularly and there may be less waste.

Comment: If you can rotate them, they're no longer identical

Comment: @harold - That's true. The sizes are identical but rectangles themselves are not. Will edit question to reflect that.

Comment: So as for that deleted answer, I think that almost works, except you might need two sections, one tiled vertically and the other tiled horizontally, and then you have to optimize over where the "split" between the sections is. Or maybe there's an explicit formula for that, because it sort of seems like there should be.

Comment: Seems like that's still too simple, but I would be surprised if such a simple variant is still formally hard

Comment: @harold I haven't seen the deleted answer unfortunately so i am not sure what i can say about that. I have been trying to come up with various solutions but have been failing. Never thought a problem about how to optimally pack rectangles would be this difficult.